# How can I put an output that contains single quotes into a string in Powershell?

Tags: string, powershell, variables

I'm having some hard time turning an output that contains single quotes ('') into a variable.
The output is this:

```
 Warning: Invalid character is found in given range. A specified range MUST 
 Warning: have only digits in 'start'-'stop'. The server's response to this 
 Warning: request is uncertain.
 % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                             Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     
0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0{
"total": 2,
"subtotal": 2,
"page": 1,
 ...
```

I think that problem is in the first single quotes. I've already tried creating the variable with single quotes, using @''@, @(''), but none of this forms is working.
How can I put this in a variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `here-string`, quotation marks are interpreted literally , see: [Here-strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules?view=powershell-7.1#here-strings)

```
$x = @'
 Warning: Invalid character is found in given range. A specified range MUST 
 Warning: have only digits in 'start'-'stop'. The server's response to this 
 Warning: request is uncertain.
 % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                             Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     
0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0{
"total": 2,
"subtotal": 2,
"page": 1,
 ...
'@
```